# How to transform specific words on sentence

Tags: assembly, emu8086

i want to transform  a sentence.
Example:
 **Today is too.To cold weather.** 
i want to do it  like this 
**Twday is tww.Tw cwld weather.**

I did something but only i transform the small letter to big(caps lock).How can i do what i disribe on my code down

```
ADD DL,32   ;i transform character from Caps lock to small  
           JMP E4      ; i go to the next tranform

E3:     SUB DL,32   ; i tranform from small to Caps lock
E4:     MOV AH,02H  ; appear DL
        INT 21H     ;
        INC SI      ; increase by 1 

E5:     LOOP E2     ; repeat the step "E2" untili "E4" 

           JMP EXIT
END:    
           LEA DX,NOINPUT
        MOV AH,09H  ; Type the message
        INT 21H 
EXIT:       
           MOV AH,4CH   ; output
            INT 21H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the bit patter of the character becomes essential to understanding what should be done.

W = 0101 0111 w = 0111 0111
O = 0100 1111 o = 0110 1111

The only bits that really matter are 5 -> 0 so 

O = 01111 = 15th letter of the alphabet 
W = 10111 = 23rd letter of the alphabet

```
mov     al, 'W'
xor     al, 0b11000             ; Changes W to O
xor     al, 0b11000             ; Changes O to W
```

You can see, doing it this way, it doesn't matter if they're upper or lower case, as those bits aren't modified.

Comment: hello and thank you a lot,can i replace 0b11000  with something else more familiar to me?i hope you get what i mean

Comment: Sure as 0b11000 = 18H = 24 decimal or even 30 octal. I just used binary so it's easier to see what `XOR` toggling bits does.

Comment: Unless you're doing this with SIMD, I don't think the XOR observation really helps, because you have to avoid modifying source letters other than `'o'`.  (With SIMD, masking `set1_epi8(0x18)` with a `pcmpeqb` result would make sense, i.e. be cheaper than a conditional blend with `set1_epi8('w')`, but for scalar I think just storing a `w` in such elements is cheaper than XOR.)  Still, nice observation that`'o' ^ 'w'` is potentially useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't notice until I'd posted that only o's were being changed to w's and not vise versa. That in itself negates the usefulness of `XOR`.

Comment: Right, but not for SIMD.  With a vector of string data in xmm0, and `xmm6=set1('o')`, `xmm7=set1(0x16)`: `vpcmpeqb xmm1, xmm0, xmm6` / `vpand xmm1, xmm7` / `vpxor xmm0, xmm1` flips all the `o` bytes to `w` more cheaply than a full pand / pandn / por blend with a vector of `set1('w')`.  (And barely cheaper than `pblendvb` on Haswell, where it's 2 uops and is port5 only.  So masking an input for `pxor` is a win without SSE4.1)

Comment: Also, the XOR idea is great if you also want to change `'O'` to `'W'`: then you can just check `c|0x20 == 'o'`, and if so then XOR, instead of checking separately for `'o'` -> `'w'` and `'O'` -> `'W'`.  The OP might actually want this, because they're downcasing.